# Open EXCEL (.xlsx) with password in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I try to open password protected `.xlsx` files (Excel 2007 format) without typing the password manually. I have installed Excel 2003 and the [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3) that converts the file when opening.

The following code works, but it prompt for the password.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook;
ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();           
Object pwd = "xxx";
Object MissingValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx",MissingValue, MissingValue, MissingValue,pwd);
```

If I use the same code to open a `.xls` File (Excel 2003), it works without prompting for the password. Opening `.xlsx` files without password protection also works fine.

How is it possible to open password protected `.xlsx` files without prompting for the password with Excel 2003 and the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack?

The trick from [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204623/opening-password-protected-excel-file-in-c-or-c-sharp-prompts-for-password-eve) changing the readonly argument (3rd) to true

```
ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx",MissingValue, true, MissingValue,pwd);
```

does not work here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening password protected Excel file in C++ or C# prompts for password even though I've passed an argument for password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204623/opening-password-protected-excel-file-in-c-or-c-sharp-prompts-for-password-eve)

Comment: No, its a little different, and the soloution from there with setting the readonly argument to true does not work here. The problem here is the use of the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack.

Comment: That question/answer implies there are further "MissingValue" arguments specified in the call to `Open`. Have you tried adding the same number as in that question/answer?

Comment: Why are you trying to open the file through Interop? Do you really want to open the Excel application? If you only want to read data from the file, use a library like EPPlus to read from the file directly. You can use the OOXML SDK but EPPlus makes reading/writing Excel sheets much easier

Comment: Another alternative that you may want to try out is [GemBox.Spreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview), you can find [here](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/SampleExplorer/Spreadsheet/Protection/XLSXEncryption) how to read a protected XLSX files.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes I tried it, but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks for the hint, I will take a look on EPPlus.

Comment: EPPlus works pretty well for me :)

Comment: I cannot endorse GemBox. There is no method exposed for <file>.Open() - even though the documented code shows to have one. As of today, that feature has been refactored and apparently is only in the paid version.

Answer (score 13):

This may be late, but for any future person with Interop, for me it worked like this:

**To open to write**

```
var WFile = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook Wbook = WFile.Workbooks.Open("myFilepath", ReadOnly: false, Password: "mypassword");
```

**To open as read-only**

```
var WFile = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook Wbook = WFile.Workbooks.Open("myFilepath", ReadOnly: true, Password: "mypassword");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer by @J1mm1995 works when trying to open files as readonly, and fails to open some excel files when you want to open the excel file for modification(ReadOnly is set to false).

I understood that this was because the Workbooks.Open() method also expected you to specify the WritePassword. The following code worked for me:

```
var WFile = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook Wbook = WFile.Workbooks.Open(path,  ReadOnly: false, Password: "mypassword", WriteResPassword: "mypassword");
```