# Open password protected document in application level add in

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, vsto

Is there a way of opening password protected Word and Excel files without manually entering password when developing an application or document level VSTO Add-in. In other words, how do I set the *password* programmatically.

I have tried to do it in the document open event but it is invoked after opening document.

Is there an event which is invoked before the document gets opened?

Basically what I want to achieve is avoid opening the document outside the my Add in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open EXCEL (.xlsx) with password in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647031/open-excel-xlsx-with-password-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This question isn't making any sense. How is the document being opened? If the user is opening it, then the user has to provide the password; if the application is opening it, then the password is provied in the `Open` method. It's not clear that an application-level add-in would "know" the password for every document that could be opened? And anyway, hard-coding passwords isn't particularly secure...

Comment: what I want to do is, avoiding opening some documents outside the add-in. And also add-in users not have to enter the password

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is - look at documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open?view=word-pia). Basically - you need to pass the password, when opening the document instead of relying on events.

For Word:

```
var WordApp = new Word.Application();
WordApp.Documents.Open("[your doc path].docx", ReadOnly: false, Password: "[your password]")
```

For Excel:

```
var ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("[your doc path].xslx", ReadOnly: false, Password: "[your password]")
```

Comment: Thanks leonardo. But what I need is to do this on my VSTO add in project. I want to avoid prompting for the password, when user try to open the document.

Comment: ah ok - can't think of a way to do it using VSTO... Maybe you can use interops and a separate windows service?